# R plotly specifying custom legend name with color parameter

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to plot using color coding on a value, and changing default legend names. Can't seem to get it to work.

This code plots what I mainly want:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y, color = y > 5, mode = 'markers')
```

Now, I am trying to change the default legend names so they are more explanatory:

```
plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y, color = y > 5, mode = 'markers', name = c('Y <= 5', 'y > 5'))
```

Does not do anything, even though plotly documentation says name is the right way to change the legend name.

I just want the legend names to be more descriptive than simple `true` and `false` as they are shown in the plot.

Comment: maybe you could create an additional column (with 'Y <= 5', 'y > 5' as factor level) to your df and color your points based on this new column.

Comment: That is what I am currently doing with cut2 as a workaround, but it is extra processing step I am hoping to avoid.

Comment: I believe `name` can be used to name a single trace. Not sure you can name multiple traces like so. Best to have a separate column like @MLavoie suggested

Answer (score 0):

Color by third variable, here added with `dplyr`.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(col = ifelse(y >= 5, ">= 5", "< 5")) %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~x, color = ~col, mode = 'markers') %>% 
  add_markers(y = ~y)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Code doesn't work anymore. Could be that due to the last plotly update you need to add the color value somewhere else

Comment: I've added the output, still works for me on 4.7.0 - did you install `dplyr`?